# Modify multiple NSTextView with commands

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to modify multiple NSTextViews with a menu bar command.  For example if the user selects "Bold" from the menu bar, the different NSTextViews that are selected update all their content to show bold.

Here is the set up I have:

```
@interface MyCustomTextField : NSView <NSTextViewDelegate>{
    NSTextView *textView;
    BOOL selected;
    ...
}
```

So basically I have my own custom class and within each custom class I have a NSTextView, a var determining whether or not this view is selected and some other stuff.

I'm able to select multiple fields however from what I've read on Apple documentation every NSTextView in the window shares one field editor.  When a user edits a NSTextView they are actually sending commands to the field editor which processes it and routes it to NSTextView.  If this is the case does that mean that I need to create my own custom field editor and route the commands to all my custom selected text classes instead?

==**edit**==
My CustomTextField classes have a variable named "selected" (see above) and by holding the shift or apple key down I'm able to "select" multiple CustomTextField instances (I put a mask in front of the NSTextView instances which catches the mouseDown message).

So by this selection, multiple instances have their "selected" attribute set to true.  As far as the first responder for the window, it would be set to the mask that shows the blue halo around all the NSTextViews.

I'm wondering if I can tell the app to accept default NSTextView commands (such as bold, italicize, etc.) and that if I supply a custom field editor, it will pass all the appropriate messages to the selected CustomTextFields which will then pass it on to the NSTextViews.

In my head the message would be passed like this:

**User Submits Text Toolbar Command** > **Custom Field Editor** > **MyCustomTextField** > **NSTextView**

Hopefully my explanation made sense or maybe I'm in LaLa land now.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single field editor -- the field editor maintains a record of your editing state and text selection, and styles it according to the menu item you select.  You can't get a single field editor to edit n fields with n contents.  There are programmatic ways you can style text in multiple views, but not by  monkeying with an editor and duck-taping it to many fields.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "different NSTextViews that are selected"? If you intend that it has the blue halo, it means that it receives key inputs (i.e., it is first responder). Only one text view can be first responder at the same time, so maybe you had something else in mind?

Comment: thanks for the comments.  Monolo, I added an edit to my post.  Hope that clarifies things.